# How to divide a number with 2 set of values..?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm performing some division operation based on user input of `from date` and `to date`...

Mysql query returns the sum of that particular day and I have to divide the sum by total number of days present in that month. But the problem is User provides 2 set of inputs .i.e from date and two date.

How to divide the sum obtained by executing query with 2 set of values?

Below is my php code:

```
   <input id="monthIpone" name="monthone" type="month"> /*enters starting month*/
    <input id="monthIptwo" name="monthtwo" type="month"> /*enters ending month*/

      <input type="button"  value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" onclick="callphp()"> /*submit*/
```

This is my calculation part:

```
    $fromdate = $_POST['monthone'];/* starting month */

    $todate = $_POST['monthtwo'];/* ending month */

    $split = explode('-', $fromdate);------------------------
                                                             |/* to 
                                                             | calculate    
    $year = $split[0];                                       | no of days
    $month = $split[1];                                      | present*/
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year);---

    $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m') as timestamp, SUM(`gridpowertotal`) as sum FROM inverterlog WHERE inverter = '" . $inverter . "' AND DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '" . $fromdate . "' AND '" . $todate . "' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m')";
    if ($result = mysqli_prepare($con, $query))
    {
       mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $timestamp, $sum);
       while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result))
       {   
           $obj = new stdClass();
           $obj->timestamp = $timestamp;
           $obj->sum = $sum;
           array_push($monthArray,$obj);

       }

        $marray = array_values($monthArray);

        foreach($marray as $object)
         {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $time = $object->timestamp;
                $obj->timestamp=$time;

                $total = $object->sum;
                $avg = $total/6;
                $cuf = $avg /((72*245)*(24*$days));/*need to caculate for 
                                                     both from date and two 
                                                     date*/
                $obj->cuf = $cuf;
                array_push($marray,$obj);

        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: From date and to date indicates a range. In your question you say _"the sum of that particular day"_ What particular day? From date, to date, or today's date?

Comment: @Solan Thrasher... User enters month and year in both  cases .i.e. From and to.... I need to calculate no of days in that month and perform division with  both  the values.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**below is my solution just moved it inside the foreach loop..**

**Before moving the code**

```
   foreach($marray as $object)
     {
            $obj = new stdClass();
            $time = $object->timestamp;
            $obj->timestamp=$time;

            $total = $object->sum;
            $avg = $total/6;
            $cuf = $avg /((72*245)*(24*$days));/*need to caculate for 
                                                 both from date and two 
                                                 date*/
            $obj->cuf = $cuf;
            array_push($marray,$obj);

    }
```

**After moving the code inside the for each loop**

```
      foreach($marray as $object)
        {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $time = $object->timestamp;
                //var_dump($time);

                /*to find no of days in a month*/
                $split = explode('-', $time);
                $year = $split[0];
                $month = $split[1];
                $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year);
                //echo "$days"."<br/>";

                $obj->timestamp=$time;

                $total = $object->sum;
                $avg = $total/6;

                $cuf = $avg /((72*245)*(24*$days));
                $obj->cuf = $cuf;
                array_push($marray,$obj);

        }
```